# Merge consecutive console outputs into one block

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio

When knitting R-Markdown in RStudio, I would like to all console outputs in one chunk to be placed together in one code block. How can this be done?

As a workaround, I write two code blocks of the same code and set `eval=FALSE` on the first block and `echo=FALSE` on the second.

````
```{r Vector Demo 2, eval=FALSE}
# examine the class and structure of vectors
class(nums)
class(char)
str(nums)
str(char)
```
```{r Vector Demo 2b, echo=FALSE}
# examine the class and structure of vectors
class(nums)
class(char)
str(nums)
str(char)
```
````

This however produces the following output:

```
# examine the class and structure of vectors
class(nums)
class(char)
str(nums)
str(char)
```

```
## [1] "numeric"
```

```
## [1] "character"
```

```
##  num [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
```

```
##  chr [1:3] "A" "B" "C"
```

What I would like is to have the output of the second chunk (i.e. Vector Demo 2b) to be placed together in one code block just like the first chunk (i.e. Vector Demo 2).
This is a sample output of how I would prefer to have my result:

```
# examine the class and structure of vectors
class(nums)
class(char)
str(nums)
str(char)
```

```
## [1] "numeric"
## [1] "character"
##  num [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
##  chr [1:3] "A" "B" "C"
```

**Note to bounty hunters:**
Better still, I would be grateful for a way to have one code chunk first print the input code, *and then* print the output code. That way I could avoid duplication and possible inconsistencies that could come with it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a solution to your problem. There are two things to do:

````
## Test


```{r echo = F, cache = F}
knitr::knit_hooks$set(document = function(x){
  gsub("```\n*```r*\n*", "", x)
})
```

```{r VectoDemo, results = 'hold'}
nums = 1:5
char = LETTERS[1:5]
# examine the class and structure of vectors
class(nums)
class(char)
str(nums)
str(char)
```
````

I have done two things here

1. Set `results = 'hold'` to "hold" printing of output after source is printed.
2. Added a document hook to collapse successive code chunks with no text in-between.

Comment: Thanks. It works as expected now. I will have to wait for a while though before I can award the bounty.

Comment: @AlexEssilfie This is basically a [previous example](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/9af9919e3a7dbb9c31bd9787b74c9a48c11db877/039-merge.Rmd) in the [knitr-examples](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/) repository. In the next version of knitr, you will have the `collapse` option to collapse the output in Markdown, as Thell pointed out in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

*With [knitr >= 1.5.23](https://github.com/yihui/knitr)*

You can get quite a bit of variety from the built-in knitr options.

For instance... get the same results as Ramnath's hook using `collapse=TRUE, results="hold"` (no global document hook needed).

If you really want **distinct source/output parts** as shown in the question then you are already on the right path. Just make use of `chunk reuse` to get the output combo without having to repeat yourself...

````
```{r}
nums <- 1:5
char <- LETTERS[1:3]
```

```{r "Vector Demo", eval=FALSE}
# examine the class and structure of vectors
class(nums)
class(char)
str(nums)
str(char)
```

```{r "Vector Demo", echo=FALSE}
```
````

The last chunk is your basic `chunk reuse` pattern.

You can see a variety of the basic combinations [here](http://rpubs.com/Thell/knitLiteralMarkdownPreview).

<sup><sub>Since you aren't making a knitr tutorial ignore the `source` and use the `rendered` examples.</sub></sup>

Comment: Your results are not the same as @Ramnath's, evident on inspection of latex/html code and visual inspection. Neither solution provides the OP's requested grouping of code with output; in both of your suggestions, the output is still grouped individually by line of command, not grouped in one html "code" or latex "Shaded"/"verbatim" block. Though I do like the simpler code, it is not meeting the OP's request. (I still don't think my code is very elegant, though I think it is the only one that meets the requested format.) Please help me understand if I'm missing something.

Comment: I do really like the rpubs link you provided, btw, nice work and demonstration of different combinations of options. I don't get the same results on all of the renderings; though I find it a little hard to follow the CSS/JS in it, the rendered result is very smooth. Thanks, I'll be referencing your rpubs page a bit!

Comment: Perhaps it's pandoc that's producing diff results. Each output is in a separate `<code>` block. I agree that Ramnath's solution is a bit specific and not safe, mine is only a little less unsafe, admittedly. http://pastebin.com/mRYvsvnC shows results of each run (done separately then combined) as an `<h1>` block. (pandoc 1.12.3, knitr 1.5; made with `pandoc(knit('file.Rmd'))`; similarly with `format='latex'` for pdf comparison, not shown.)

Comment: It's obvious at this point that I'm not using rmarkdown (nor do I use rstudio, though I don't think that's critical), so this is almost certainly a difference between `render()` (from rmarkdown) and `pandoc()` (from knitr). Perhaps Alex should weigh in on which he is using (he lists "R-Markdown" which I take to be the format, not necessarily the package).

Comment: no difference with `collapse=TRUE`. I'm using knitr-1.5 and pandoc-1.12.3.

Comment: @r2evans, it is the knitr version.  1.5 didn't have collapse yet.  Updating answer to reflect required knitr version, will clean comments in a bit.

Comment: Shame on me for assuming the CRAN-provided version vice github. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@Ramnath's solution appears a bit simpler than this one. His is likely better in many (most?) circumstances, but this alternate solution might be good in others:

````
Test.

```{r echo=F,cache=F}
knitr::knit_hooks$set(document=function(x) {
    paste(rapply(strsplit(x, '\n'), function(y) Filter(function(z) !grepl('# HIDEME',z),y)), collapse='\n')
})
```

```{r Vector Demo 1, results='hold', tidy=FALSE}
nums = 1:5
chars = LETTERS[1:5]
# examine the class and structure of vectors
{ # HIDEME
print(class(nums))
print(class(chars))
str(nums)
str(chars)
} # HIDEME
```
````

Notes:

1. Use of the brackets (`{` and `}`) around the code keeps the output together. However, commands that return things and don't print things will be silent (unless last), ergo my `print` addition to those lines. This may or may not be a factor depending on your actual commands.
2. In my install, for some reason, `tidy` defaults to `TRUE` which was shifting my first `# HIDEME` comment to before the left bracket (and I have since edited to code to reflect the definition of `nums` and `chars`). Odd, but likely a side-effect of source tidying. This is why I force `tidy=FALSE`. Since this might affect how you present your code, using it as a per-block option at least limits the pretty-printing problem.
3. The `# HIDEME` is really just "comment-character plus some obscure string" for easy `grep`ing.
4. The `knit_hook` I added is not "simple," but I find it less likely to have side-effects on other chunks within a document. This could likely be done with more specificity (I know @Ramnath has worked on other `knitr` problems with Yihui, so there could be more "correct" ways to do this with more specificity.) (I tried and failed to do this as an "output" hook instead of "document" hook. Homework.)